# Prusa I3x and repetier host heat problems

Tags: prusa-i3, g-code, repetier, repetier-host

I've saved settings in the slicer for pla and abs, set the default bed temp to 90 and extruder to 185. No matter what settings I select to print with, the bed temp sets to 110 and the extruder to 230 when I send a job to print which I don't want. If I then control the heat manually, repetier or the printer  seems to ignore my requests.
If I try to kill the job I keep getting a box coming up asking me to switch the heats off; I select yes and nothing happens.

If I use the emergency stop the heats switch off.

Comment: Can you please include the slicer that you are using, and also the g-code start sequenced (that gets prepended to each print job)?

Comment: @james all slicers control your temperatures, set and verify your parameters on each gcode to validate everything is right. Try to send a print that you want not the ones that you don't want to avoid motor and heating stops.

Comment: also, there are paramters that slicer includes to "optimize the prints" but these lines need to be changed or removed from extra settings.

Comment: What slicer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. You may set the temp in Repetier but when you run the gcode it will send any of the temp settings in the file. So you may set 210 °C first but if 200 °C is in the G-code the printer will take that (as the gcode is sent one instruction at a time). However I also noticed that after the automatic bed leveling any manual settings on the printer are reset to the G-code (I assume the file is re-stating the temp after bed leveling) So I have to override the file temp after the bed leveling is complete.
2. I now use OctoPrint and it has a cool feature : temp offsetting, you can specify an offset for every temperature the OctoPrint server sends to printer; e.g. in your file it is set to bed: 110 °C and extruder: 230 °C you can tell OctoPrint to take 20 °C off all bed temps sent and 45 °C off any extruder tempperatures sent. It's great for tweaking the temperatures of your G-code without editing or re slicing, just change the temperature offset and reprint.
3. I noticed on a previous firmware version for the I3 mk2s Repetier did not connect properly to the printer this problem disappeared in the latest Prusa firmware (v3.1).  One of the symptoms I noticed was the temperature settings were not taken by the printer.
4. Some slicers have a setting to have sticky parameters, i.e. set temperature once don't bother re-sending. However if this was turned off, it is possible that the generated G-code repeatedly send the temperature settings with every instruction, continuously resetting and overriding these values. (OctoPrint temperature offsets would correct this)